# Google Maps Elevation Service

Tags: google-maps, elevation

I have this function which is invoked upon clicking a button. The function creates a marker at a predefined position. I then use the elevation service for the given point. When I click the button, the alert message (I've put it there for diagnostics) displays 'undefined', and then the marker appears (in fact the marker should appear *before* the alert box!). I've tried my best to identify the source of the problem but in vain. Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

```
  function buttonClicked () {
     addNode(someLat, someLong);
     alert(getElev(markers[0]));
  }

  function addNode(lat, lng) {
      var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: LatLng,
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
      markers.push(marker);
  }

  function getElev (marker) {
      var ht = 0;
      var locations = [];
      var clickedLocation = marker.getPosition();
      locations.push(clickedLocation);
      var positionalRequest = {
        'locations': locations
      }

      elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function (results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK && results[0]) 
               ht = results[0].elevation;
      });
      return ht;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the alert here and it should work. The function inside getElevationForLocations does not occur within getElev, but is called asynchronously. so ht is not set within getElev.

```
  elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK && results[0]){
           ht = results[0].elevation;
           alert(ht);
      }
  });
```

Comment: I was wondering, though. Is there a way that we wait for the asynchrnous call to complete before we leave getElevationForLocations?

Answer (score -1):

```
altitude = 0; // Declared with out "var" make it superglobal 
function buttonClicked () {
 addNode(someLat, someLong);
 alert(getAltitude());
}

function addNode(lat, lng) {
  var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: LatLng,
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
  markers.push(marker);
}

function getElev (marker) {
  var locations = [];
  var clickedLocation = marker.getPosition();
  locations.push(clickedLocation);
  var positionalRequest = {
    'locations': locations
  }

  elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK && results[0]) 
           setAltitude(results[0].elevation);
  });
}

//getters and setters for altitude 
function setAltitude(a){
    altitude = a;
}
function getAltitude(){
    return altitude;
}
```

Comment: You really should explain why this solves the OP's problem.